# How to run qt-gui in docker?

Tags: docker, qt, qt5, alpine-linux

I've tried several solutions that I've managed to get hold of, but I'm facing with the following error inevitably:

```
$ QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM="native" sudo docker run -it --privileged -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -e QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM="native" -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 -v /dev:/dev -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw qt-alpine
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331264
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331264
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331264
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331264
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331264
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331264
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331264
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/app/simple-qml/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :1
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

Host system: Ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache qt5-qtbase-dev qt5-qttools qt5-qt3d-dev g++ cmake make

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN qmake-qt5 && make

CMD ["sh", "-c", "QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native /app/simple-qml/simple-qml"]
```

I'm just trying to avail myself of `Qt 5.15` with `3dextras`, etc. support in `qml`. So the files are just examples from `qt3d5-examples` in the directory. So .. actually, the files does not matter, I'm just trying to establish the way of running `qt`-`opengl`-app in `docker`.

Comment: Try running before `xhost +` in your host

Comment: @eyllanesc Wow! It's made some progress! But I have the following error:
```
Qt3D.Renderer.Backend: bool Qt3DRender::Render::GraphicsContext::makeCurrent(QSurface*) makeCurrent failed
Failed to make context current: OpenGL resources will not be destroyed
```